# Document Translator invalid key

Tags: microsoft-translator

I use Document Translator version 2.1.1 and I have Azure subscription keys. I installed this application with version 2.9.4 on another PC. I generated new Key 1 and Key 2 on Azure and introduced them in account page of the application. Upon saving, the message is that the key is invalid. I did not use the application recently, so I did not consume 2M characters. I use Surface Pro X with Windows 11 ARM64 from Insiders Preview and it shows as x86 architecture application in 32 bit platform.

Answer (score 0):

You will get an "Invalid key" message if the key doesn't match the Azure region you selected. The region shows up as "Location" property in the Azure Translator resource. Be sure to select the same region of the resource in the app settings.